# Ideal topology of a Binary Tree?

Tags: tree, computer-science

What is exactly meant by Ideal Topology of a binary search tree (BST)? I understand that any search for a value should be done in a logarithmic time complexity, but does it need to be "exact" log n? Does the tree have to be a complete tree except for the last row (as in heaps)? Or should it be approximately balanced?  I really tried searching but couldn't get any decent answer.

For example:

```
                              25
                            /    \
                          10      50
                         /          \
                       9             62
                                    /   \
                                   55    70
```

Does this tree have an ideal topology?

Or is ideal topology the best balanced BST that can be constructed from a set of data?  So it's not an identity of a tree that can be checked?

What is ideal topology of a BST?

Answer (score 0):

your example is not balanced because you can not put a 55 under the 62 because it is bigger than the 50 you can insert in the smaller half any value less than 50 or 50 if you want .
Ideal topology means that the tree is easy to access and manipulate,plus it is sorted in a generic way (in your case acssendigly and decsendingly ).
it can be a topology of even and odds were the even are on the right and the odds are on the left .
I hope i answered your question.